# GMail not visible in Unity panel

Tags: unity, gmail

I am trying to get GMail integration working with my brand new 12.10 installation.
So far I have installed unity-mail and unity-webapps-gmail packages. I have also added two of my gmail account in Online Accounts tool.

The current state is I can start GMail app from dash, which open GMail tab in Firefox for the first of my email accounts. However, I don't see the "GMail" option in Unity panel it top right - only Empathy.

Any ideas? I would also appreciate info on how to debug Unity panel icons in general.

Comment: Turns out that the indicator was missing in dconf.
com.canonical.indicator.messages.applications contains a list of visible apps in "messages" indicator. After adding: 'GMailmailgooglecom.desktop' I can finally see GMail on the list, however it doesn't show if there are any new messages on gmail.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was already pointed out in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-webapps-gmail/+bug/1245027.

In order to solve it, you have to install the package available here:
https://launchpad.net/~justinmcp/+archive/webapps-ppa. More precisely:

1. to add ppa:justinmcp/webapps-ppa to your system's Software Sources, open a terminal and enter:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:justinmcp/webapps-ppa
   ```
2. to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, including the PPA ppa:justinmcp/webapps-ppa you just added:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

It works fine for me (Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy, 64-bit).

See also these questions: [ubuntu 13.10 webapps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389350/ubuntu-13-10-webapps/408704#408704), [Gmail Webapps and 13.10 - Unity and Message Me Menu Integration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361267/gmail-webapps-and-13-10-unity-and-message-me-menu-integration?rq=1)