# Gmail Webapps and 13.10 - Unity and Message Me Menu Integration

Tags: unity, firefox, webapps

I've just installed 13.10 and while I was using Firefox, the system prompted me to install the webapps for sites like Gmail, Facebook, Launchpad, and so on.

What happens is that, after the first moment of the installation, the Unity icon that appear for Gmail app remains as only an icon that opens another window directly into Gmail. Before, there was an integration with Unity because when clicking the icon it directed me to the tab where Gmail was opened in Firefox.

Besides the Unity integration there's the message menu integration. With Facebook app, I receive notifications on the Me Menu near the watch whenever someone sends a message, but with Gmail it's null, it doesn't even appear in the Me Menu. It happens with Firefox and Chrome.

Any clues?

Comment: You might want to check out the Geary email client, which has easy setup for gmail and which integrates nicely with the messaging menu. It won't help for the rest though.

Comment: I'm well aware of desktop clients. I prefer Thunderbird in that case. But I rather like the shortcut to the web version :)

Answer (score 2):

This bug was already pointed out in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-webapps-gmail/+bug/1245027/comments/11

In order to solve it, you have to install the package available here:
https://launchpad.net/~justinmcp/+archive/webapps-ppa. More precisely:

1. to add ppa:justinmcp/webapps-ppa to your system's Software Sources, open a terminal and enter:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:justinmcp/webapps-ppa
   ```
2. to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, including the PPA ppa:justinmcp/webapps-ppa you just added:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

It works fine for me (Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy, 64-bit).

See also these questions: [GMail not visible in Unity panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224566/gmail-not-visible-in-unity-panel?lq=1), [ubuntu 13.10 webapps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389350/ubuntu-13-10-webapps/408704#408704)

Comment: I got an update to the GMail Webapp today, in 13.10. The description said that the login mechanism had been backported from Trusty. Upon starting the app from the Launcher, I got prompted to log into my Google account again via Online Accounts, and now the app seems to be working again (I also got the integration prompt again).

Comment: Does anyone know if the WebApps fix mentioned in this PPA works with 14.04 also? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for. But you can in Chromium and Chrome go to Tools and create an application shortcut of this website. These links can be added to the launcher (icons are most of the time bad looking). This will not open een extra tab but a completely new screen without address bar etcetera.